# Next.js Middleware rewrite / redirect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

For some reason, the invalid url error occurs

index.tsx

```
import checkAuth from "@/Middleware/checkAuth";
export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
    checkAuth(req)
    return {
      props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
export default function HomeAdmin() {
    return (<div className='adminPanel'>
    </div>)
}
```

checkAuth.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export default function checkAuth(req:NextRequest) {
    console.log(req.nextUrl);
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url))
    // return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/', req.url))
}
```

invalid url error
Also req.nextUrl is always undefined

I tried on localhost\ip\domen there is no difference, there is always a url error

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck with something like this, in `next@^13`. This is a middleware example, but the same concept should apply.

```js
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    const updatedUrl = request.nextUrl.clone();
    updatedUrl.protocol = 'https:';
    updatedUrl.host = 'www.proxied-host.com';
    updatedUrl.port = '';

    return NextResponse.rewrite(updatedUrl);
}
```